# How make clouds less square?

Tags: volumetrics

I am trying to create clouds using cycles, but they are looking  too squared.
I am using volume and the modifiers are:

[image]

The mesh I am using is a simple meatball.

[image]

[image]

How can I create clouds with more details?

Comment: Is there any specific reason for you to go through the process of adding an empty volume object and then a Mesh to Volume modifier on it, instead of just setting up a volumetric shader on your mesh directly?

Comment: btw, go to Light Paths and turn volume bounces up 1 or 2, it'll give you some lighter color options

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to increase the "Voxel Amount" in your *Mesh to Volume* modifier. You can think of a voxel as a 3D pixel. The more pixels/voxels, the finer the resolution. This will increase the computations required, so adjust by small increments to avoid soft/hard locking your PC.

Comment: Thanks, I had set to 64, but I didn't notice any change. I had to change to a higher number.

Comment: @ViniciusMorais You're welcome :) It's also a little difficult to see a difference without enough samples because the edges are so soft.